# Scheduled crontab with valid command doesn't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I am using whenever gem for my rails app on Ubuntu server to schedule sitemap generation. This is how my crontab -l looks:

```
0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/thomas/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -s sitemap:refresh --silent'
```

It should execute script every 2 hours, but it doesn't. But command is valid, because when I go to folder myapp/current and run it, then it creates sitemap correctly.

I was searching stackoverflow and there are many different answers, most of them what i tried doesn't work.

What I am doing bad? Thanks.

Comment: Add `>/tmp/cron-output.log 2>&1` to the end of your line, change it to execute every minute, and show us the output from `>/tmp/cron-output.log`.

My initial guess is that `bundle` isn't in `crontab`'s `PATH`. You could try finding `bundle` via `which bundle`, and then add: `PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/bundle/directory` on a line by itself at the top of the `crontab`.

Comment: First off you can do this in crontab, `0 */2 * * * <command>`, which will run your command on the 0th minute of hour 0, 2, 4, ..., 22.  Also, when you say it works when you cd into the directory then run the command, what exactly do you that works?  Not sure why you have `/bin/bash -l -c` in the beginning of your cron command.

Comment: drewyupdrew: I don't understand Cron, its created command from Whenever gem (Ruby on Rails). Exactly works that script create sitemap, which doesn't exist. So command is okey. Maybe path before is bad, but as I said, it was created from Whenever gem and it should work.

Comment: Will: Thanks for advice, but I don't know what should I do. I just wrote which bundle command and this is result - /home/thomas/.rbenv/shims/bundle

Comment: @Anubix Don't forget the `@` before people's username, or else we don't see it.  


When you say that "the command is valid", I assume this is what you mean works: cd into `/home/thomas/myapp/current` and then run the command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -s sitemap:refresh --silent`.  Is that correct?  Is that what you're saying works fine?  If so, then please post the output of the command, or does it create a file or something?  Please post and let us know as much info as possible.

Comment: @drewyupdrew Ok sorry :) As you wrote, I go to cd home/thomas/myapp/current and run that command. There is no result in terminal, but it creates sitemap.xml.gz file.

Comment: @Anubix ah I see.  So why are you running `bash` on that file?  I don't understand the `/bin/bash -l -c` portion of your cron

Comment: @drewyupdrew Don't know why is there bash part, it was created by Whenever gem. But I looked through topics on StackOverflow and many people use it as well (and it works them)

Comment: @Anubix ok sorry not really sure how to help you without posting more info.  It's strange that the cron was created by whenever gem and it's not working, I'm assuming you used the command `whenever --update-crontab`, or had `whenever` create the cron for you and you manually added it to crontab yourself.  Anyway, you need to look for clues in logs and post errors for people to help you.  If the cron actually ran and you're sure of it, common places to look are: `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/cron/`, etc.

Comment: @drewyupdrew I am looking on this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/593585/cron-doesnt-run-tasks-because-bin-bash-var-log-cron-log-permission-denied  maybe it's the same problem, but I don't understand solution.

Comment: Here is output from cron-output.log  -> /bin/bash: bundle: command not found

Comment: You should check if the command alone works to you. Once it does, set up the crontab. Otherwise, you won't know if it is an issue in the command itself or in the cronjob.